# Prove sequence (of integrals) is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, upper-lower-bounds

I've got the function $f(x)=x^2-6x+8$ and the sequence of integrals 
    $I_n=\int_3^4 (x^2-6x+8)^n dx$ 
$ n>0 $ 
I have to prove that $I_n$ is convergent. We are taught that a sequence converges provided it is monotone and bounded.

My idea would be as follows: $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(3,4)$ and because n>0 we can say $f(x)^n$ is decreasing as well. To find the bounds I plug the values of the integral bounds, and since it is decreasing it would mean $f(4)<f(x)<f(3)$ and therefore $-1<x<0$. Is that right? And if so, is the answer complete?

Comment: What makes $f$ decreasing? It is increasing on $(3,4)$ because the derivative $2x-6=2(x-3)$ is positive.

Comment: $f(x)= (x-3)^2 -1$ is **increasing** on $[3,4]$. $(I_n)_1^\infty$ is bounded iff $(|I_n|)$ is bounded above.

Comment: Oh, I messed up pretty bad then. I thought of negative and positive values of f(x) instead of the values of derivative of f(x). Anyway, is the logic behind it fine?

Comment: @RaduGabriel  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$-1\le (x^2-6x+8)=(x-2)(x-4)\le 0$$

and therefore by MVT  $\forall n \, \exists \, c_n \in (3,4)$

$$|I_n|=\left| \int_3^4 (x^2-6x+8)^n dx \right|=\frac1{4-3}\int_3^4 (8+6x-x^2)^n dx=[f(c_n)]^n\le 1$$

Answer (score 0):

It is false (since $f(x)$ is increasing in $(3,4)$), and so the answer is not complete!

A hint can be:

Show that $-1 \leq f(x) \leq 0$ for any $x \in (3,4)$. And then use [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to show that $I_n \to 0$.

Alternatively, you can show that (since $f$ has a constant sign) $$ |I_n| = \int_3^4 |x^2-6x+8|^n \leq \int_3^4 |x^2-6x+8|^{n-1} = |I_{n-1}|$$
So $|I_n|$ is decreasing (in $n$) and thus (since $\geq 0$) converges. 
Therefore, to show that $I_n$ converges it's enough to show that this limit is $0$.

Suppose the limit is $l > 0$. Then for $n$ even and big enough, we have $0 \leq f(x)^n \leq \frac{l}{2}$ for any $x \in (3+ \frac{l}{4} , 4)$

So $|I_n| \leq \frac{l}{2} \cdot (1-\frac{l}{4}) + \frac{l}{4} < l$.

Therefore, we must have $l=0$ and so $I_n \to 0$.

Comment: I think that's too complicated for me, there should be an easier way. It's clear I've messed up the monotony, but what confuses me is the fact this is a sequence, so basically going to infinity, right? How do I find bounds of such a thing? Is it unbounded above because n goes to infinity? Do I have to calculate the limit as it goes to infinity? I have no idea, honestly.

Comment: Ok, so, $n$ goes to $+\infty$. To find a bound on $I_n$ you should find some number that is bigger than $|I_n|$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. No $n$ is unbounded, but $I_n$ can be bounded. Yes, you have to evaluate the limit as $n$ goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: I have edited my post, is it more understandable for you now?

Answer (score 0):

Using Riemann integral only.

Note that $|f(x)| = 1$ only at $x = 3$, we split the interval into two parts. For every $c \in (3,4)$, note that $|f|$ is decreasing, we have 
\begin{align*}
\varlimsup_n |I_n| &\leqslant \varlimsup_n \int_3^c + \int_c^4 |f(x)|^n\mathrm d x \\
&\leqslant \varlimsup_n \int_3^c 1\mathrm d x +\varlimsup_n \int_c^4 |f(c)|^n\mathrm dx\\
&= c-3 +\varlimsup_n (4-c) |f(c)|^n \\
&= c-3 \quad [|f(c)| < 1]\\
&\to 0 \quad [c \to 3^+]. 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\sqrt{t}+3$ then
$$I_n=\int_3^4 (x^2-6x+8)^n dx=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2}\int_0^1(1-t)^nt^{-\frac12}\ dt<\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1t^{-\frac12}\ dt<1$$
Indeed
$$I_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2}\int_0^1(1-t)^nt^{-\frac12}\ dt=\dfrac{(-1)^n\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac32)}$$
then
$$|I_n|<\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$